# Listen to Advanced Oracle Queue (AQ)

Tags: go, advanced-queuing

I'm checking Go ability to migrate an existing C++ application.
One of the main task is to listen actively (no polling) an Advanced Oracle Queue.
In Java and C++ there are existing libraries supporting it since a long time.

I could not find anything similar in Go (libraries & examples). 
Could you help me with that?

Comment: I have a library for this, I'm asking now about open sourcing it

Comment: Hi @jwells131313, do you have already a public repository for this library?

Comment: Sorry it's not public yet.  I'm trying to get legal to ok it being made public.  There is also this, but it's pretty difficult to use: https://github.com/rana/ora

Comment: github.com/rana/ora is an oracle driver but there is nothing regarding Advanced Oracle Queues processing with this driver.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  But it can be used with OracleAQ, you just have to do the queries yourself.  I'm very sorry it's taking so long to get through the legal red tape

Answer (score 1):

I have an implementation whereby I'm using the "gopkg.in/goracle.v2" package to connect to Oracle, along with the generic Go library "database/sql".
The way I did it, I have the code to read from the AQ in a PL/SQL procedure which I'm calling from my Go code. Although this is not the best approach - and I'm actually going to change it so that it doesn't rely on a stored oracle procedure - it works. The code looks something like the following:

**Oracle PL/SQL proc:**

```
PROCEDURE GetAQMessage ( out_content    OUT VARCHAR2, in_acknowledge IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N' )
IS 
   dyn_sql   VARCHAR2(32000);
   l_content VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

   dyn_sql := '
      DECLARE 
         l_payload MESSAGE_TYPE := MESSAGE_TYPE (NULL);
         l_msg_id             RAW(16);
         l_dequeue_options    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
         l_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T; 
      BEGIN
         DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
            queue_name => '''|| v_queue_name ||''',
            dequeue_options => l_dequeue_options,
            message_properties => l_message_properties,
            payload => l_payload,
            msgid => l_msg_id
        );
        :b_output := l_payload.message;
      END;';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dyn_sql USING OUT l_content;
   -- Return the content to the OUT parameter
   out_content := l_content;

   -- Permanently removes the message from the Queue
   IF in_acknowledge = 'Y' THEN
      COMMIT;
   END IF;

END GetAQMessage;
```

**Go code:**

```
func GetAQMessage(transaction *sql.Tx) (string, error) {
    var outResult string
    var resErr error
    var debug int

    configuration = conf.Read()

    //Run the command
    _, resErr = transaction.Exec(`BEGIN CONSENT.GETAQMESSAGE(:1,:2) ; END;`, sql.Out{Dest: &outResult}, "N")

    return outResult, resErr
}
```